# confirm the status of your Key Vault

Tags: azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I have azure functions and Keyvault.  both of them are part of Virtual Private network and they have RBAC implemented as access policies.however when i use Key Vault reference in my Azure function's configuration. I keep getting this error

The portal is not able to confirm the status of your Key Vault reference at this time. Please confirm the status directly from the app by checking whether the environment variables have resolved. Click here to access the app.

Answer (score 5):

> The portal is not able to confirm the status of your Key Vault
> reference at this time. Please confirm the status directly from the app by checking whether the environment variables have resolved. Click here to access the app.

This error has mentioned that in your function app ***system-assigned managed identity*** not able to connect to your Key Vault please check that ***status to be enable*** like below

***In your function app -> identity under setting ->system assigned -> status -> Save***

[image]

Try to check in your key vault, App should have the ***proper access permissions to read the credentials stored in the keyVault.*** Make sure you have granted `GET` for secret permission. Your app should be able to reach the Key Vault to be able to resolve a reference issue successfully.

***Go to keyvault -> Access policies under setting -> Add access policy -> save***
[image]

[image]

[image]

### Update:

[image]

- ***System assigned identity*** has one to one relationship with the azure resource that assigned to each resource can only have one system assigned managed identity
- ***User assigned managed identities*** are created standalone azure resources that can exist independently from other azure resources, so key vault reference may occur an error like *confirm the status* and single user assigned managed identity can shared across multiple azure resources

Comment: Thanks for the response. But This did not work. I already RBAC setup. so I am not using system assigned Identity. instead i am using user assigned one. I think that is what creating an issue ?

Comment: I have tried but I just dont see Go to keyvault -> Access policies under setting -> Add access policy -> save option as RBAC is enabled, and I cant even change to vault access policy. can you please suggest ?

Comment: Thanks i will get back. I guess i dont have access to change the settings. need to follow up with few people and see if this works. in any case will keep you posted. thanks.

Comment: I have tried checking the connectivity.  My Key Vault is in Private network. so i had to create a VM in same network and did nslookup. which it resolved it.  so i think even though we get this blue icon. and since I was accessing azure portal from public network. it was not able to resolve and i was never getting that green tick. however i am stuck in my code while accessing keyvault from Azure function. it throws Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed: Service request failed

Comment: As you are experiencing the 400 (Bad Request) from the server, which means missing some configuration issue. Check the configuration details like clientID which you are passing